# Test whether a process left any orphans behind

Tags: process

I don't need to wait for them, I just need a yes or no.

I'm executing a program that I know is going to fork (and the children are likely to fork too). If run correctly, it should take care of all the its children and exit them when it finishes. I need to write a test that checks if this is true. Orphaned processes get assigned to the init process, so I cannot see them in pstree anymore.

Bonus points if I can get a list of their PIDs so I can send SIGKILL to them. Ideally if it's something POSIX-y, so it would work on *BSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process terminates, the PPID of its children is set to 1 (adoption by init), but the PGID (process group identifier) and the SID (session identifier) don't change.

The process's children probably don't change their process group, unless they're intended to be daemons. Assuming they don't, start the process to be tested in its own process group. Call `setpgid(getpid(), getpid())` from your test framework, after forking and before calling `execve` to execute the program being tested. Call `kill(-test_program_pid, 0)` (`kill` with a negative `pid` argument and the signal value 0) to test whether there is a running process with the PGID `test_program_pid`. Pass `SIGKILL` as the signal argument to kill them all.

```
test_program_pid = fork();
if (test_program_pid) {
    waitpid(test_program_pid, &status, 0);
    if (kill(-test_program_pid, 0)) {
        record_failue("some child processes were not terminated properly");
    }
    kill(-test_program_pid, SIGKILL);
} else {
    setpgid(getpid(), getpid());
    execve("/program/to/test", …);
}
```

An alternative method would be to create a temporary file and open it in the program that you're testing and nowhere else. If the program calls `execve`, make sure that the file descriptor is opened without the `O_CLOEXEC` flag (or call `fcntl(fd, FD_CLOEXEC, 0)`). This method assumes that the program doesn't go and close the file descriptors that it doesn't use explicitly. You can then run `fuser /temp/file` to list the processes that have this file open, and `fuser -k /temp/file` to kill them. A variant of this approach that works even with programs that close file descriptors they don't use, but assumes that the program doesn't change its current directory, is to create a temporary directory and change to that directory to run the program.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Using `setsid()`  would probably work too.

Comment: How might I manage this from a bash script?

Answer (score 5):

One way to find these would be to use `ps -ef`, looking for rows where the parent-id is "1", e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
orphans="$(ps -ef | awk '$3 == 1{ print $2; }')"
echo "Processes which might be orphans: $orphans"
```

However, *many* processes have "1" as their parent.  Determining which are interesting to you can best be done by remembering which child processes your program created.

If you happen to know the *login name* (and/or *user-id*) under which these processes are created, you can eliminate some of the possibilities.  The first column of `ps` can show (depending on the type of system) either the *login name* or corresponding *user-id*. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) offers some help here, but it's easy to find systems which differ — and the documentation reflects this:

- FreeBSD 10, for instance, does not show the *login name* for the `-f` option.   With just `ps -ef`, it shows the process-id in the first column, and does not show the parent's process-id. It requires the `-l` option to show (instead) the *user-id*.
- OSX gives the user-id in either case (`ps -ef` or `ps -efl`).
- Given the `-l` option, Solaris 10 shows process flags in the first and second columns.  That's mentioned in POSIX, although the *content* of the flags is unspecified (because the content differs across *Unix* platforms).
- Linux gives the login-name and process flags as per POSIX.

As you can see, for some subset of the available systems, `ps -efl` would give the "same" result for the first three columns.  For anything more general, you'd have to look at the header (first line) and determine which column contains the information corresponding to the process owner (*login name* or *user-id*) and the process id and *its* parent's process-id.

For a given system (knowing the usable options for `ps`, and knowing whether to match the *logon name* or *user-id*), you could use `awk` to match *that* field as well, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
orphans="$(ps -ef | awk -v user=$LOGNAME '($1 == user && $3 == 1){ print $2; }')"
echo "Processes which might be orphans: $orphans"
```

Here I used `$LOGNAME`, to account for POSIX's use of the term *login name*, which could be misleading (since in principle the processes could be via `sudo`, while POSIX's use of the term implies that they came via a "login").

Further reading:

- [What are the Zombie and the Orphan Processes and how to kill them?](https://web.archive.org/web/20230928021248/https://linuxg.net/what-are-zombie-and-orphan-processes-and-how-to-kill-them/)

Comment: from my recent experience with systemd on ubuntu orphaned processes (e.g. `disown`'ed) don't necessarily get "adopted" (to continue the metaphor) by PID 1. When an interactive shell is launched in an emulator  like gnome terminal, some process descendent from within the gui process branch seems to pick up the orphans.

Comment: It would be pretty impossible for me to determine if one of the processes belonging to PID 1 were one of my own - I don't know what their names will be and this test doesn't have the internal information about what is being forked. In fact, I'm testing that internal mechanism as a black box - if I relied on its internal info, I would be mostly just testing a tautology.